# select and deselect a option in a select box several times

Tags: jquery

Maybe can here somebody help me. I have this situation: A select box with severa options and I want to change the selected option depending of a option value introduced for the user in a textbox. BUt till now I don't get sucess, I try everything but always after I select something it is still selected and doesn't want to diselect. My select box is like this

```
<select id="slt-np" class="form-control">
    <option selected="" value="0">Selects one</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

and the handler code in jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#textbox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var selectedoption = $("#cont").children("#slt");//This is to take the select 
        $(selectedoption).find("option[value='"+$("#textbox").val()+"']").prop("selected",true); //select the option with value in textbox
        if ($(selectedoption).find("option[value='" + $("#npip").val() + "']").prop("selected") == false) { //if this option have been not selected
            $(selectedoption).find("option[value='" + $("#npip").val() + "']").prop("selected", true); //I select it now
        } else {
            $(selectedoption).find("option[value='" + $("#npip").val() + "']").prop("selected", false); //if was selected I deselect it
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add this to a jsfiddle?

Comment: The users - are they supposed to enter text or value (that is will they enter 'one' or '1')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write something like this:

```
$("#textbox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var textin = $("#textbox").val();
        $("#slt-np").val(textin);
    }
});
```

This will check what the user has written and finds the same text as value of a selected option.
If the user input is the text of the option:

```
$("#textbox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var textin = $("#textbox").val();
        var optionsel = $('#slt-np').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == textin; }).val();
        $('#slt-np').val(optionsel);
    }
});
```

Comment: You have missed $('#slt-np').val()... It should be like: $('#slt-np').val($('#slt-np option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == $("#textbox").val(); }).val());

Comment: @Taleeb didn't test it. Editing the answer, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You should just use:

```
$('#slt-np').val('Your value');
```

and it will select your value.